# I can't extract border_type=city from an wales-latest.osm.pbf file

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, openstreetmap

I have got wales-latest.osm.pbf from http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/great-britain.html.  This is the OSM file for Wales.  If I export http://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=19/51.50387/-3.08467 as XML, I get the key:value pair border_type:city.

When I parse the wales-latest.osm.pbf file using the following code, it can't find any border_type:city pairs:

```
@Override
    protected void parseWays(List<Way> ways) {
        for (Way w : ways) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append("  Nodes: ");
            long lastRef = 0;
            for (Long ref : w.getRefsList()) {
                lastRef+= ref;
                sb.append(lastRef).append(" ");
            }
            sb.append("\n  Key=value pairs: ");
            boolean isCity=false;
            for (int i=0 ; i<w.getKeysCount() ; i++) {
                isCity=isCity||(getStringById(w.getKeys(i)).equals("border_type")&&(getStringById(w.getVals(i)).equals("city")));
                sb.append(getStringById(w.getKeys(i))).append("=")
                        .append(getStringById(w.getVals(i))).append(" ");
            }

            if (!isCity){
                continue;
            }

            System.out.println(sb.toString());
        }
    }
```

If I replace `"city"` with `"territorial"` then it can find matches.

Does the border_type:city not exist in the pbfs?  Is this just related to geofabrik.de pbfs?  I've tried the Scotland osm.pbf file too, and that didn't work either.

Comment: I suggest to either ask the Geofabrik people directly or compare your PBF with one of the other [extracts](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm#Country_and_area_extracts). But I don't see why specific borders should be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

One issue is you are only looking at ways, not at relations. As an example, take [Cardiff](http://www.openstreetmap.org/browse/relation/1625787). It is in Wales, tagged with border_type=city, but because you are only checking ways your code will not find it.

You want to parse both ways and relations.